# Project not building after creating unit tests in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nunit

A product with lot of interdependence among projects. Initially creating unit test for one project. Successfully able to create tests and using InternalsVisibleTo() for accessing non-public class members of that project. But when I build the project, because it has dependencies its throwing errors. Before creating tests there were no errors.

List of errors:

> Failed to load '..\xxx1.dll' because it is not a valid .NET assembly :
>   RegAsm
>
> The command "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm"
>   xxx1.dll /tlb:"..\xxx1.tlb" /verbose" exited with code 100.
>
> The output property is not set for the project. Please check to make
>   sure you have specified valid combination.

Comment: Since you mention interdependencies, can you make sure you set the project build order for your new project properly as well

Comment: Nope, I have not set build order for new project. Since its a test project, it depends only one the project(for which tests are created) right ? And I have cross checked. New project is build at last and its dependencies match with project being tested. What do you might recommend me to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved after changing "Solution platforms" to "x64". Since one project among dependencies was indirectly depending upon a project that needs to be build for x64 machine.